Is there such thing as a common native Korean name?
I notice that, like Vietnamese names, the absolute majority of Korean names I've heard of (of celebrities, politicians, etc.) sound like Sino-Korean, they all seem to have Chinese/Hanja spellings, especially when written in Chinese text (par for the course), but surprisingly also Japanese text. All common family names are of Chinese origin and their cognates are also quite common in Vietnam too. So is there any common native (non-Sino-Korean) name at all?

It is not yet common but recently I have seen it more frequently, In a recent korean drama "The kidnapping day", a character is named "별" (byeol) which cames from a native word that means "Star".

Hangul Last name is not common
Hangul First name is common (but Hanja first name is more prevalent)
for example,
박-나래 / 김-봄소리
you could find it by searching "고유어 이름" or "순우리말 이름" on google.
